# How to show that this function respects the strict ordering of its input.

Tags: vectors, median

Suppose you have a vector $\pmb x=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ where each entry is drawn from a continuous distribution and $n$ is even.

Then, denote $i^*=\{1\leq j\neq i\leq n:|x_i-x_{j}|=\mbox{med}_j|x_i-x_j|\}$
($i^*$ always exists and is unique with probability one if $n$ is even and the $\pmb x$'s are drawn from a continuous distribution).

Consider now the vector $\pmb a=\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ with:

$$a_i=2x_i-x_{i^*}$$

The proposition I'm trying to prove is the following: under the conditions stated above, the vector of values of $\pmb a$ has no tie.

At first the claim may seem counter-intuitive as the vector of values of $\{x_{i^*}\}_{i=1}^n$ can contain a (and often many) tie(s) even if the entries of the vector $\pmb x$ are drawn from a continuous distribution . Yet, using a computer program I found that it seems that $\pmb a$ doesn t contain tie (even when $\{x_{i^*}\}_{i=1}^n$ does).

It's very easy to write a computer program to test this 
for many random numbers [here in R], but without a better understanding of the problem, it is like shooting in the dark (I still put the code here as it might help with any ambiguity in my description of the problem).

```
n<-122
x<-rnorm(n)
a2<-a1<-rep(NA,n)
for(i in 1:n) a1[i]<-median(abs(x[i]-x[-i]))
for(i in 1:n) a2[i]<-(1:n)[order(abs(x[i]-x))][floor(n/2)+1]
a3<-2*x-x[a2]
sum(duplicated(a3))
```

## Edit:

Following Yuval Filmus's comments below and the fact that I have been stuck on sub-cases of this proof for a week I have decided to adopt a different strategy. The proposition has now been changed to the more constraining version whereby the entries of $\pmb x$ are assumed to be drawn from a continuous distribution. I will devote my efforts to the separate question of showing that in the application I have in mind this is indeed the case. I now believe this second approach would prove more fruitful.

Comment: The sequence $x=\{3,2,4,1\}$ has even length and no ties, and $1^*=\{2,3\}$, so again this does not have a unique median.

Comment: @AndySoffer: thanks for your second comment. It sheds light on an aspect of the problem I had overlooked. I believe the reformulation of the problem I edited in allows to circumvent the difficulty you outlined with the initial formulation (the code has been updated too, now).

Comment: Testing this using random numbers is not convincing, since for random numbers there will never be any duplicates.

Comment: @user1963 There will also be no duplicates in the $\mathbf{a}$ vector. In fact, with truly random numbers (say uniform in some interval), with probability 1 there will be no duplicates in either vector.

Comment: @user1963 A tie corresponds to some non-trivial linear relation between the $x_i$s, one of finitely many possible ones. Each one happens with probability zero.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I also fail to understand why testing this claim using non duplicated x's is not convincing when the proposition  assumes that the x's contain no duplicates. I would really appreciate it if you could expend on this comment.

Comment: @user1963 That's not at all what I'm saying. I'm saying that if the vector is generated randomly, then you shouldn't expect any duplicates regardless of your claim, just because a duplicate is a zero probability event.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: are you saying that the claim is provable (in the sense of being true with probability 1) if we can assume that the $x$'s are drawn from a continuous distribution? That would only be slightly more restrictive than what I initially had in mind, and given the changes brought by Andy Soffer's remark it may not make that much of difference. Beside, atm, I'm still stuck on two subs-cases so I may have to content with the solution you seem to suggest. If this is the meaning of your comment, I would gladly add this to the question as an edit. –

Comment: @user1963 Yes, if the input vector is drawn i.i.d. from a continuous distribution then the derived vector is duplicate-free with probability 1.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I will update the question then so that your comment can be turned into the basis for an answer. I'm still curious how the $\pmb a$ can have no tie when the $\{x_i^∗\}_{i=1}^n$ clearly do, so I guess a formal proof of the reformulated proposition would still be interesting.